# In php file <fieldset> tag is not display

Tags: php, html, css

I have included two css

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

After css i placed my Html tag

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
</fieldset>
```

But output not displayed. If i removed my  css code then the fieldset tag is working. 
Kindly help me to fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: it seems like `style.css` have somewhere blocking css code. Check and comment that code. BTW we arn't able to reproduce this problem so limited help can be given only

Comment: CAN I SEND MY COMPLETE STYLE.CSS CODE TO U

Comment: We will need to see your style.css code.  just edit this question and place it there

Comment: This question is not about PHP,  and if you think of ignoring other users asking for clarification then perhaps you shouldn't ask here at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your css block the code and somewhere in css you have set the display property `none`

```
<fieldset style="display:block">
  <legend style="display:block" >Personalia:</legend>
</fieldset>
```